# How to solve jquery datatables repeated search and pagination rows?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, web, htmx

I am using HTMX (for Ajax requests) and JQuery Datables in a django project, but I am experiencing a weird issue. Indeed the datatables work fine, but **repeat search and pagination rows** when I navigate history using the browser **forward or back buttons.**

*I assume it has to do with htmx given that when issuing Ajax requests the new content will replace the old one and the tables will probably be reinitialized with no page refresh*

I'd be happy if you could help. Thanks